# OpenCV easy way to call fillConvexPoly() on 3d area?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I have a grayscale 3D image represented as a numpy array.  Dimensions are height x width x depth.  Given a `square = [p1,p2,p3,p4]` I want to call `fillConvexPoly(square, 100)` on every depth layer of the array.  I know I can just loop through the depth and call the function a few hundred times, but I feel like doing so fails to take advantage of the fact that I am working with a numpy array.  Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you actually just using a square? Are the points different for each layer/slice/channel in the third dimension? If you're simply just filling a cube inside your 3D array, you can do this with numpy indexing and don't at all need to use `cv2.fillConvexPoly()`. But if the points are different for each layer, I don't think there's a simple way to do this without iterating, since you need to go through both the list of points *and* the layers.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds To be more exact, it's a rectangular prism I want to fill.  So the points p1-p4 form some kind of rectangle, and I want to use the exact same p1-p4 for each layer.

Comment: Perfect! All you need in that case is indexing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is index the rectangle in the first two dimensions, and that will select that rectangle in every channel in the third dimension. Then you can simply fill with whatever values you like. For e.g., I'll create a stack of 100 random images that are 5x5, and assign every pixel on the inside 1, leaving just the border of the image the random values it started with. Even though here just the first image is printed, each one looks like the first except the values around the edge.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> imgs = np.random.rand(5, 5, 100)
>>> imgs = np.random.rand(5, 5, 100)
>>> imgs[:, :, 0]
array([[ 0.17818592,  0.7427181 ,  0.83685674,  0.27231489,  0.037665  ],
       [ 0.61994589,  0.64282216,  0.20543185,  0.65049771,  0.52236919],
       [ 0.78862153,  0.86612292,  0.48208187,  0.1233576 ,  0.18561781],
       [ 0.09628382,  0.08812067,  0.50085837,  0.92871428,  0.28052041],
       [ 0.87715376,  0.38269949,  0.76995739,  0.83079243,  0.90698188]])
>>> imgs[1:4, 1:4] = 1
>>> imgs[:, :, 0]
array([[ 0.17818592,  0.7427181 ,  0.83685674,  0.27231489,  0.037665  ],
       [ 0.61994589,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.52236919],
       [ 0.78862153,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.18561781],
       [ 0.09628382,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.28052041],
       [ 0.87715376,  0.38269949,  0.76995739,  0.83079243,  0.90698188]])
```